# PHP image resize to exactly 256 x 256 pixels with stretching

Tags: php, image, image-resizing

I want to resize an image to exactly 256 x 256 pixels.

I'm currently using...

```
$image_p = imagecreatetruecolor($imgMaxWidth, $imgMaxHeight);
imagecopyresampled($image_p, $source, 0, 0, 0, 0, $imgMaxWidth, $imgMaxHeight, $imgWidth, $imgHeight);
```

It only accepts `Maximum Width` and `Maximum Height`.

If I upload 615 x 339 pixels image, I will get an image resized to 256 x 141 pixels.

Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what are you doing but your code should works

I've tried this and it works:

```
<?php
// The file
$filename = 'test.jpg';
$source = imagecreatefromjpeg($filename);

// Set your height and width
$imgMaxWidth = 256;
$imgMaxHeight = 256;

// Content type
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');

// Get new dimensions
list($imgWidth, $imgHeight) = getimagesize($filename);

// This is the code you post
$image = imagecreatetruecolor($imgMaxWidth, $imgMaxHeight);
imagecopyresampled($image, $source, 0, 0, 0, 0, $imgMaxWidth, $imgMaxHeight, $imgWidth, $imgHeight);

// Output
imagejpeg($image, null, 100);
?>
```

Comment: I did it same way It shows `The image “http://localhost/imageupload/untitled.php” cannot be displayed because it contains errors.` this error................ I also changes the destination folder like this `imagepng($image, photo_gallery/, 100);`

Comment: The second parameter is the filename (string), so:
`imagepng($image, "photo_gallery/my_image.png", 100);`

Comment: It creates `my_image.png` file in `photo_gallery/` folder bit it is not a image file i can't open and its actual size is 0 bytes

Comment: I think (I don't remember very well) if you want to create a png using `imagepng(...)` you have to use `imagecreatefrompng( $my_original_image )` where `$my_original_image` is a png image.

Check: [http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagepng.php](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagepng.php)

Comment: Yes I have all my images in png and im using `imagecreatefrompng()` function aswell